# Fix the Help Center Privileges duplication

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges, help-center

On the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) are two categories: *"Reputation & Privileges"* and the seemingly redundant *"Privileges"*. Both have a small entry count and were likely intended to be merged.  They probably should be merged or the first should be renamed to *"Reputation"*.  Showing the word *"Privileges"* twice looks like a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's intentional to have those two categories be separate. We're working on a redesign of the privileges list that will be rolling out next week, hopefully - that page will be more of a track-your-progress type of page, which really needs to be distinct from the static reference pages in the rest of the help center.

Additionally, the "Reputation & Privileges" section will have a few more articles added to it; we've just had a rather large backlog of things to work on and it's taking longer than I anticipated to get those up.

**UPDATE:** While it was intentional, there has been enough confusion that we'll change the name of the category so it doesn't include "privileges" in the title. That change will happen in the next week or so.

Comment: No problemo; the title duplication simply looks odd.

Comment: re: the Update.  I kept my mouth shut; I figured there'd be enough future "complaints" to give this legs again. :-)

Comment: Hey Laura, can you please take a look in [this answer I just wrote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244611/152859)? If you agree about the suggested change, it would be great if you can change it. :-)