# Meaning of "A user can unprotect any protected question"

Tags: support, privileges, protected-questions

On the [15k privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) privilege page, we find

> Any question, even a deleted question, can be protected and unprotected, subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - The question must be at least a day old
> - **A user can unprotect any protected question**

What does the latter statement mean? Can *any* user unprotect a question? Can any other *15k user* or mod unprotect a question?

**UPDATE:** [bug filed and fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250041/protect-questions-privilege-page-has-confusing-wording).

Comment: I bet it was referring to the reputation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the past, 15k users could protect questions and unprotect only questions they protected themselves.

This was changed, so what you read there means that user with this privilege can unprotect any question regardless who protected it in the first place. This is useful for example in cases of questions automatically protected (by Community account) that high rep user believe should be unprotected: in the past, flag was required, now any 15k user can do it.

As for the odd position as "restriction" it's due to the old text, that can still be seen [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130723192844/https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions):

> ### Which questions can be protected?
>
> Any question, even a deleted question, can be protected and unprotected, subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - The question must be at least a day old
> - A user can unprotect a question protected by him or herself, but not one that has been protected by someone else

So in the past, that was indeed restricted. This whole block better be changed to something like:

> ### Which questions can be protected?
>
> Any question at least a day old, even a deleted question, can be protected and unprotected. A user with the privilege can unprotect any protected question.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what does it do there as restriction :)

Comment: No problem @nicael, I've also contacted someone who can perform the change, hopefully she will agree. :)

Comment: The complete sentence should be something like "A user with the privilege can unprotect any protected question"

Comment: True @Braiam, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A 15k user or mod can unprotect any protected question. But there is especially dumb wording: how "A user can unprotect any protected question" is a restriction?.. or its me misunderstanding...