# "Protect Questions" privilege page has confusing wording

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, help-center, protected-questions

The wording on the [Protect Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) privilege page is confusing and would benefit from being clarified. See these questions on [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244609/meaning-of-a-user-can-unprotect-any-protected-question) and [meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286669/what-does-a-user-can-unprotect-any-protected-question-mean).

Suggested wording from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244611/244304) is to replace this:

> ### Which questions can be protected?
>
> Any question, even a deleted question, can be protected and unprotected, subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - The question must be at least a day old
> - A user can unprotect any protected question

with the following:

> ### Which questions can be protected?
>
> Any question at least a day old, even a deleted question, can be protected and unprotected. A user with the privilege can unprotect any protected question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't see the need to even mention deleted questions in the description, that's a very advanced feature for very advanced users. If you've got 15k rep, it's more of a "Oh, neat, I can protect & unprotect deleted posts too" sort of thing. That's a detail more for the FAQ.

Revised wording:

> ### Which questions can be protected?
>
> Any question at least a day old can be protected and unprotected by users that have the privilege.

Short. Easy. Simple.