# "Protect Questions" privilege page doesn't mention the new answer requirement

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center, protected-questions

A new feature was implemented a few weeks ago from [Prevent protecting questions under certain circumstances](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274324/prevent-protecting-questions-under-certain-circumstances/274328) -

> We recently implemented a change to protected questions based on the
>   suggestion by Robert with a few modifications. 15k users will still be
>   able to protect but in order to do so **the question must have at least
>   one answer by a new user aka a user with < 10 rep on the site** (which
>   is the required rep limit to answer protected questions).

However, I recently went to check for protection and it wasn't available due to the new restriction that [isn't mentioned](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) on the [privilege pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions). It took me a few minutes to find the meta.SE question linked. Can the privilege page be updated to reflect the change?

This isn't the same question as ["Protect Questions" privilege page has confusing wording](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250041/protect-questions-privilege-page-has-confusing-wording), despite similar wording.

Comment: This just bit us on PMSE, so it would be nice to have the documentation fixed. Incomplete documentation is a bug. :)